# Console Log is not showing in React-Native

Tags: android, react-native, google-chrome

When trying to run console.log error occurs in terminal

> Error: Unable to resolve module `./debugger-ui/ui.bcd3f9d1.js` from ``:

[image]

When open http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui/, showing warning:

> DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui/ui.bcd3f9d1.js.map: HTTP error: status code 500, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE

[image]

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution please? I am facing the same issue